# ¿Como obtener intervalo entre un rango de horas?

Tags: php, date

Estoy tratando de obtener horas entre un rango de horas, ejemplo:

Tengo 2 horas: `23:00:00` (El inicio) y `01:00:00` (El fin)

Ahora a través de un bucle for trato de obtener de 30 en 30 minutos la hora inicial hasta que llega al final. Ejemplo:

```
23:00:00
23:30:00
00:00:00
00:30:00
01:00:00
```

Estoy utilizando el siguiente script:

```
public function test($horas){

    for($i=0;$i<count($horas);$i++){

        for($j=$horas[$i]->hora_ini;
            $j <= $hora[$i]->hora_fin;
            $j = date("H:i:s", strtotime($j)+(30*60))){
            echo $j.'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona, solo funciona cuando son horas por ejemplo de `08:00:00` a `14:00:00` pero no de `23:00:00` a `01:00:00`

Comment: No me queda claro el resultado que quieres optener, si la cantidad de horas o la hora que sería. ¿Puedes explicar un poco que resultado quieres?

Comment: Si los datos tuvieran la fecha sería muy fácil, ahora bien, con las horas solamente es algo complicado... habría que manejar el hecho de que haya una diferencia de días en la fecha, como es el caso, pues las `23:00` horas corresponderían a una fecha y las `01:00` horas a otra (el día siguiente... o varios días después, depende). Al parecer @aldanux he ideado una función para hacer ese cálculo. Es cuestión de probar. De todos modos, si puedes recuperar las fechas de cada hora, no tendrías que pasar por una función hecha a mano que, tratándose de fechas y horas, te puede fallar con facilidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Ese es el _chiste_ del OP poder calcular entre dos horas cuales pueden ser entre un día al otro y sin fechas. El caso es que cuando se inicia el objeto `DateTime`  (**sin fechas**) te añade el día actual  ([ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9d9e81961f10986fb4eb0a9023daac1c5d8a990))... teniendo eso en cuenta tienes que sumar  simplemente 1 día más si el inicio es superior al del fin de horas... parece complicado pero no lo es...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Combine un poco de lo que dijeron todos y solucione el problema. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te he creado una función cuales te guarda el periodo de horas con los intervalos preestablecidos en minutos (modificables).

Usando la clase y sus métodos de [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php#class.datetime).

<kbd>**[Ver Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfb022734766510a8a486cffae3446de7bb38019)**</kbd>

```
function intervaloHora($hora_inicio, $hora_fin, $intervalo = 30) {

    $hora_inicio = new DateTime( $hora_inicio );
    $hora_fin    = new DateTime( $hora_fin );
    $hora_fin->modify('+1 second'); // Añadimos 1 segundo para que nos muestre $hora_fin

    // Si la hora de inicio es superior a la hora fin
    // añadimos un día más a la hora fin
    if ($hora_inicio > $hora_fin) {

        $hora_fin->modify('+1 day');
    }

    // Establecemos el intervalo en minutos        
    $intervalo = new DateInterval('PT'.$intervalo.'M');

    // Sacamos los periodos entre las horas
    $periodo   = new DatePeriod($hora_inicio, $intervalo, $hora_fin);        

    foreach( $periodo as $hora ) {

        // Guardamos las horas intervalos 
        $horas[] =  $hora->format('H:i:s');
    }

    return $horas;
}

print_r( intervaloHora( '23:00:00', '01:00:00' ) );

//** Resultado **// 
Array
(
    [0] => 23:00:00
    [1] => 23:30:00
    [2] => 00:00:00
    [3] => 00:30:00
    [4] => 01:00:00
)
```